# Selectively using variables when applying conditional independence

Tags: probability

When applying conditional independence (e.g. $\pmb{X}\perp\pmb{Y} | \pmb{Z}$ ; $\pmb{X},\pmb{Y},\pmb{Z}$ denote random variable vectors) in a probability term with conditioning $\Pr(\cdot|\cdot)$, do I need to make sure the probability term matches exactly this conditional assumption, and cannot pick variables in the condition that make up $\pmb{Z}$?

Here is a statement that follows from the above, if I am allowed to "pick variables"

Let $X, Y, Z, W$ be random variables.
If $X\perp Y | Z$, then $X\perp Y | Z,W$.

I did not find a proof for this. Here is my attempt:

\begin{align}
\Pr(X,Y|Z,W) &= \Pr(X|Y,Z,W)\Pr(Y|Z,W)
\end{align}
Because $X\perp Y|Z$, and in the first term, $Z$ is given, therefore, $\Pr(X|Y,Z,W)=\Pr(X|Z,W)$. Then, $\Pr(X,Y|Z,W)=\Pr(X|Z,W)\Pr(Y|Z,W)$. By definition of conditional independence, the statement holds.

But there is a bit of a circular logic going on here. If $\Pr(X|Y,Z,W)=\Pr(X|Z,W)$, then already, the statement $X\perp Y | Z,W$ is automatically true. I cannot use the conclusion to prove itself.

Therefore, the above proof strategy does not work.

Comment: Please explain the downvote?

Comment: While I didn't downvote, you may have received it because your question(s) are a little confused.  You have several questions here and your question would benefit from picking one of them and making that the one you want answered.  The other questions do provide context, but you could rephrase them as your thoughts to show how they support the main question.

Comment: @postmortes I have edited the question per your recommendation. Please have a look, thanks!